Maximize number of regions whose sides reach all vertices of $K_n$
Suppose we put $n$ points (vertices) in the plane and connect all pairs with edges, i.e. draw the complete graph $K_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. (For simplicity, we can assume no $3$ vertices are collinear and no $3$ edges are concurrent.) Aside from the unbounded outer region, the edges divide the plane into some convex polygonal regions (that do not have lines inside them). A vertex $V$ is said to touch a region if one of the region's sides is part of an edge that has $V$ as an endpoint. My question: what is the maximum possible number of regions which touch all $n$ vertices? I'll call them special regions for the rest of this question.
As an example, if $n = 4$ there can be either $0$ special regions (if one point is inside the triangle of the other three) or $4$ (each triangular, touching both diagonals of the quadrilateral which together contain all vertices). So $4$ is the answer for $n=4$.
Special regions are somewhat weird objects, apparently inaccessible from a combinatorial perspective, i.e. they only exist geometrically. There is also some geometric weirdness in that edges are only line segments. As such there may be no explicit formula for the maximum, but I am also interested in bounding this maximum from below or above (or at least giving a growth rate). I am further interested in point arrangements that tend to increase the number of special regions (for example, it seems like higher counts happen when the points form a convex polygon, but I don't know why that should be).
My progress: I am relatively convinced that the answers for $n$ up to $8$ are $$(n=3: 1), (n=4:4), (n=5:6), (n=6:7), (n=7:8), (n=8:10)^*$$ I put $1,4,6,7,8,10$ in OEIS and none of the results appeared to have any relation to this problem. Odd regular $n$-gons, $5 \le n \le 9$ have $n+1$ special regions but this breaks at $11$ which has only 1 special region. Other than these small cases, I don't know how to go about even bounding the maximum below or above for specific $n$, because more points become very difficult to deal with, even with a computer. Induction might help, but I'm not sure how to approach it because adding a point adds new lines which can push regions closer to, or over, the specialness threshold.
For context, I thought of this problem while trying to think of an interesting and nontrivial problem, so there's no source. I would appreciate any help on this or a closely related problem e.g. using lines instead of line segments, adding a convexity requirement, etc.
*A 10-special-region octagon, found after programmatically checking tens of thousands of random octagons
